# Uber API's https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/ endpoint does not work as for all my rides

Tags: uber-api

I'm having trouble receiving details about past rides.
The scenario is the following:

I do a GET request at https://api.uber.com/v1.2/history?offset=0&limit=10
using, of course, the required headers, and it works just fine.

However, if I do a GET request at https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/request_id_here, using the same headers from the request above, and instead of request_id_here is use valid request ids also received from above, the response would be:

> {
>       "message": "cannot find trip",
>       "code": "not_found"
>   }
>   with the code 404

I said valid request_ids because I got them from the /history request, and because if I misspell one, it will return a 422 "code": "invalid_request_id" response.

The even stranger thing here is that the first id I got from the history works just fine everytime, but the other 9 won't work at all.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is there any way that these rides get removed after a while? At least from the API side, because I can still find them on their mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using two different endpoints:

- v1.2/history :  it is Driver API endpoint and require your valid driver user to authenticate to be able to get a list of rides.
- v1.2/requests/request_id_here : this is Rider API endpoint - and you will need to use specific Rider user account acces_token in order to get a trip info. So you cant use previous driver access token. By default, only details about trips your app requested will be accessible. If your app has all_trips scope, however, trip details will be returned for all trips irrespective of which application initiated them.

Please check the Uber documentation:  https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get

Comment: Hey @Sasa I am having bit of issue using uber-api, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282763/uber-deeplink-and-universal-url-crashes-android-application?noredirect=1#comment87776275_50282763